# Как грамотно сгруппировать упорядоченную коллекцию?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Есть класс, например такой

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object SomeObject { get; set; }
}
```

SomeObject может быть экземпляром любого класса (на самом деле не совсем любого, но к вопросу это не имеет отношения)

Есть коллекция экземпляров этого класса

```
public List<MyClass> Items { get; set; }
```

Эту коллекцию нужно выводить на форме. С этим проблем нет, при помощи TemplateSelector я выбираю нужный шаблон элемента списка в зависимости от типа `SomeObject`. Но теперь встала задача группировать идущие подряд элементы в один контейнер, если их `SomeObject` одного типа. Подскажите, как грамотно это сделать?

Пока у меня есть такая идея. Разбить коллекцию `List<MyClass>` на коллекцию коллекций, типа `List<List<MyClass>>` и именно ее использовать в ВМ. Но, возможно, у кого-нибудь есть другие идеи?

Comment: Для этого используется `CollectionViewSource` + `GroupDescriptions`. Вот [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027(v=vs.110).aspx). Я напишу пример позже.

Comment: Окей, я смог реализовать через GroupDescriptions только группировку по типам: все объекты данного типа группируются вместе, даже если между ними и есть объекты других типов. Наверное, это не совсем то, что нужно :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для случая, когда нужно сгруппировать *все* экземпляры данного типа вместе, подойдёт такой код:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- конвертер, переводящий тип объекта в строку -->
        <local:TypeNameConverter x:Key="TypeNameConverter"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SRC" Source="{Binding}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <!-- группируем по строке - имени типа -->
                <PropertyGroupDescription Converter="{StaticResource TypeNameConverter}"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SRC}}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <!-- шаблоны для разных типов элемента -->
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyBigClass}">
                    <TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding Text}"/><Run Text=" / "/><Run
                        Text="{Binding MoreText}" Foreground="Gray"/></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyExpensiveClass}">
                    <TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding Text}"/><Run Text=": "/><Run
                        Text="{Binding Price}" Foreground="Red"/></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="Header">
                                <Run Text="{Binding ItemCount, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <Run Text=" items:"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <!-- скрываем заголовок, если только один элемент -->
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Header"
                                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
class TypeNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? "null" : value.GetType().FullName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Исходные данные:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MyBigClass : MyClass
{
    public string MoreText { get; set; }
}

public class MyExpensiveClass : MyClass
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

DataContext = new MyClass[]
{
    new MyClass { Text = "first" },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "second", MoreText = "big" },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "third", MoreText = "very big" },
    new MyExpensiveClass { Text = "fourth", Price = 1.23M },
    new MyExpensiveClass { Text = "fifth", Price = 9.99M },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "sixth", MoreText = "not so big actually" },
    new MyClass { Text = "seventh" },
    new MyClass { Text = "eighth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" }
};
```

Результат:

[image: результат 1]

---

Если и правда нужно группировать, не изменяя порядок, так, чтобы группы каждого типа могли быть по нескольку раз, придётся немного усложнить.

Для начала, надо добавить к базовому типу `MyClass` свойство `int GroupId`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Конвертер нам больше не нужен, меняем `PropertyGroupDescription` на такое:

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupId"/>
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

Далее, заводим процедуру, которая расставляет эти самые `GroupId`:

```
void AssignGroupIds(IList<MyClass> items)
{
    Type prevType = null;
    int id = -1;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        if (type != prevType)
            id++;
        prevType = type;
        item.GroupId = id;
    }
}
```

Применяем эту процедуру перед присваиванием:

```
var items = new MyClass[]
{
    new MyClass { Text = "first" },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "second", MoreText = "big" },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "third", MoreText = "very big" },
    new MyExpensiveClass { Text = "fourth", Price = 1.23M },
    new MyExpensiveClass { Text = "fifth", Price = 9.99M },
    new MyBigClass { Text = "sixth", MoreText = "not so big actually" },
    new MyClass { Text = "seventh" },
    new MyClass { Text = "eighth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" },
    new MyClass { Text = "ninth" }
};
AssignGroupIds(items);
DataContext = items;
```

Получаем:

[image: результат 2]

Обратите внимание, что у `first` и `sixth` нет заголовка, т. к. это одноэлементная группа (а мы для таких групп этот самый заголовок отключили).

Comment: Да, нужно именно не меняя порядка. Похоже, это то что нужно. Попробую позже, спасибо! )

Comment: @iRumba: Пожалуйста!