# Как сворачивать элементы listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть listbox, который используется в качестве дерева ( плоский список, в котором дополнительно хранится уровень вложенности элемента ).
Вот xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Repeater"                                                           
         Items="{Binding CollectionOfValues}"                                        
         SelectedItem="CollectionOfValues.SelectedItem">                             
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                           
        <DataTemplate>                                                               
            <Border Background="Transparent"                                         
                    Padding="{Binding Level,                                         
                            Converter={StaticResource PaddingConverter}}">           
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                
                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent">                        
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Part}"                        
                                       Margin="3 0 0 0"/>                            
                        </StackPanel>                                                
                    </StackPanel>                                                    
            </Border>                                                                
        </DataTemplate>                                                              
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                          
</ListBox>
```

Код конвертера:

```
public class LevelPaddingConverter : IValueConverter                                               
{                                                                                                  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    
    {                                                                                              
        if (value is int level)                                                                    
        {                                                                                          
            return new Thickness(20 * level + 10, 2, 5, 5);                                        
        }                                                                                          
        return new Thickness();                                                                    
    }                                                                                              
                                                                                                   
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {                                                                                              
        throw new NotImplementedException();                                                       
    }                                                                                              
}
```

Все строится, можно увидеть граф, но он не сворачивается. Я думал expander как-то заиспользовать, но не совсем понимаю, как в моем случае это сделать

Comment: `но не совсем понимаю, как` - ну вам что надо свернуть? Каждый элемент списка? Если да, то вы уже переопределили `ItemTemplate`, что мешает в нем прописать `Expander`, внутри которого будет контент?

Comment: нет, не каждый элемент, а группу элементов с одним `Level`.

Comment: О группировании надо наверно в самом вопросе сразу указывать? Ну чтож, это тоже [просто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566335/220553), указываете по каким значениям группировать, делаете вид нужный для группы, получаете то, что надо.